# How to solve 'Program type already present: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture'?

Tags: java, android, guava, android-workmanager

I am trying to use WorkManager 1.0.0-alpha09. and getting this error:

```
Program type already present: 
com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture

Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: 
com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture, sources=[Unknown source 
file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

If i use version 1.0.0-alpha08 or less. I don't get this error, but i need public constructor

```
public Worker(Context context, WorkerParameters workerParams)
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Take a look at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116154359.

The workaround is:

```
implementation("android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-alpha09") {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture' 
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error: **org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'**................................**Caused by: com.android.builder.merge.DuplicateRelativeFileException: More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'**

Comment: Try cleaning Android Studio's cache. Select 'File > Invalidate Caches / Restart' and then click the 'Invalidate and Restart' button. Clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: @Rahul May I know, is there any side-effect of doing so? Will it pick a wrong version of listenablefuture library from other dependencies?

Comment: No, the interfaces are identical. There is no side-effect.

Answer (score 107):

In my case, I had to add the following configurations to app's module `build.gradle`:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
}
```

It happens because some dependencies use `com.google.guava:guava` and `com.google.guava:listenablefuture` together. It causes a dependency conflict.

Comment: In which build.gradle did you put this? Just in the root or any sub item?

Comment: @GillisHaasnoot put it in app's module.

Comment: just to provide more detail about the location: it's in the app's `build.gradle` and configurations should be at the `same level` as android{} and dependencies{} are.

Comment: @AyejuniIlemobayoKings where to place above config in `app/build.gradle` ? under `android` ?

Comment: @AyejuniIlemobayoKings inside `app/build.gradle` and outside `android` block.

Comment: thank you worked for me just add in ```app > build.gradle inside ```  ``` android  {}```

Answer (score 20):

I merely added `implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'` at the end of my app gradle file and the error went away.

Answer (score 2):

I am using `ListenableFuture` that comes from the work manager.

```
implementation("android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0")
```

So excluding `exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'`, didn't work for me.

I was using a dependency that internally used `androidTestImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:42"` that internally used `com.google.guava:guava:25.0.1-android`. This was causing the problem for me.

Upgrading `com.google.truth:truth` to `43` solved it for me.