# com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, javacompiler

I cannot compile my project, scenario i converted one of my activity to kotlin using Android Studio's "Convert Java File to Kotlin File" and fixed all errors for code that was not properly converted.

Java complier log:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
>   
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
>   
>   com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
>   
>   com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: null, Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 110666 > 65536 ; # fields: 67264 > 65536)

**build.gradle (app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        versionName "2.2.4"
        versionCode 13

        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix ".d.5"
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "server"

    productFlavors {
        prod {
            applicationId "com.test.test"
            dimension "server"

            buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_HOST", "\"http://www.test.com\""
        }

        dev {
            applicationId "dev.test.test"
            versionNameSuffix ".dev"
            dimension "server"

            buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_HOST", "\"http://localhost/test\""
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.schibstedspain.android:leku:6.0.0'

    implementation 'com.github.sparklit:adbutler-android-sdk:1.0'
    implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:5.0'
    implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.9.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    def nav_version = "1.0.0-alpha09"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    // use -ktx for Kotlin
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
    // use -ktx for Kotlin

    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:1.1.1'
    implementation 'devlight.io:navigationtabbar:1.2.5'
}

configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

**build.gradle (project)**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My bad (FIXED now)
Add this to build.gradle (app) in defaultConfig

> multiDexEnabled true

**build.gradle (app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        versionName "2.2.4"
        versionCode 13

        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27

        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix ".d.5"
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "server"

    productFlavors {
        prod {
            applicationId "com.tfwm.lighting"
            dimension "server"

            buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_HOST", "\"http://www.test.com\""
        }

        dev {
            applicationId "dev.tfwm.lighting"
            versionNameSuffix ".dev"
            dimension "server"

            buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_HOST", "\"http://localhost/test\""
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.schibstedspain.android:leku:6.0.0'

    implementation 'com.github.sparklit:adbutler-android-sdk:1.0'
    implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:5.0'
    implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.9.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    def nav_version = "1.0.0-alpha09"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    // use -ktx for Kotlin
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
    // use -ktx for Kotlin

    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:1.1.1'
    implementation 'devlight.io:navigationtabbar:1.2.5'
}

configurations.all {
    // this is a workaround for the issue:
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52521302/how-to-solve-program-type-already-present-com-google-common-util-concurrent-lis
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

[java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex in Android Studio 3.0 [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47187662/java-lang-runtimeexception-com-android-builder-dexing-dexarchivemergerexception)

> Also solution is **NOT REQUIRED** if your **minSdkVersion** is set to 21 and above

Comment: This solution is not required if you set 'minSdkVersion 21' in Module: app build.gradle file. As 21 and above platforms are default multiDexEnabled.

Comment: Noted. Thank you! @Sahil

Comment: I have used multiDex enabled in my gradle. But still error :(