# How to resolve com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException?

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, flutter, build.gradle

I am getting this exception while trying to build flutter app and tried various solutions but none of them helped me yet. I am looking for solution on this as its been a time consuming pain to resolve this.

app/build.grade:

```
   defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.quickcarl.client"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        // needed to fix release build crash
        // ndk {
        //     abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
        // }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            // applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'

    // Twilio Video library resides on jcenter
    implementation 'com.twilio:video-android:1.1.0'
    // required for twilio VideoActivity
    implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.7'
    // firebase analytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    // firebase authentication
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    // firebase cloud messaging
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'

    // required to resolve this issue:
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52521302/how-to-solve-program-type-already-present-com-google-common-util-concurrent-lis
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

top level build.grade:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
```

Current setup already has `multidexenabled=true`, and `implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'` which seemed to be the solution to this issue and was recommended in other posts, but that has not solved the issue for me.

I keep getting exception which points to `jetified-play-services-measurement-base-16.3.0.aar` dependency about which I have no idea what to do with. Looking for solution on how to fix this exception.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users/<username>/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/jetified-play-services-measurement-base-16.3.0.aar/ad108baaea5302bc328d2bf417082421/jars/classes.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30965) solution worked for me perfectly, so I didn't have to change alpha and beta versions or update dependency versions.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all the `alpha`, `beta` versions of the library with stable versions as below:

```
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
```

And change the dependencies to latest versions as below:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0
```

Comment: Ok, there's some progress after making above changes. Although now, I am getting this exception: `jetified-play-services-measurement-sdk-16.4.0.aar/c95d832adb9327e41d22114a667fba52/jars/classes.jar`. Original exception was : `jetified-play-services-measurement-base-16.3.0.aar/ad108baaea5302bc328d2bf417082421/jars/classes.jar`

Comment: In the same way, check that all your dependencies, plugins have latest verions. Moreover, do verify that you have placed `google()` at the first place in repositories block.