# Duplicate class com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture found in modules guava-20.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava:20.0)

Tags: android, firebase, guava, firebase-in-app-messaging

When I use `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.2.0'` in my `app/build.gradle`, I get this error:

```
Duplicate class com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture found in modules guava-20.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava:20.0) and listenablefuture-1.0.jar (com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

What I also have in my `app/build.gradle` is this:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:16.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'
implementation 'android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Maybe one of the libraries that I am using already includes support for the In-App Messaging dependency, and then it becomes redundant? Thank you.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

I found the solution at [How to solve Program type already present: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52521302/how-to-solve-program-type-already-present-com-google-common-util-concurrent-lis). user2297550 said:

> I merely added `implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'` at the end of my app gradle file and the error went away.

That was the solution for me. Now I have this and my app compiles correctly:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'
```

Comment: But, What it means ? We are adding some new dependency instead of removing something duplicate happned and Error gone..!!!

Comment: @JaiminModi According to https://github.com/google/guava, "Guava is a set of core Java libraries from Google that includes new collection types (such as multimap and multiset), immutable collections, a graph library, and utilities for concurrency, I/O, hashing, caching, primitives, strings, and more! It is widely used on most Java projects within Google, and widely used by many other companies as well."

Comment: Currently the latest version is `implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.2-android'` https://github.com/google/guava/releases

Comment: There is an even newer release: `implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre'`

Comment: Version `27.0.1` worked for me after getting "Cannot access class 'com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture'." error with `io.ktor:ktor-auth:1.5.2` for whatever reason.

Answer (score 381):

**2020 Solution**

Google knows about this error so they made a special package to fix the conflict.

Add this to your `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'
```

Comment: LOL, this is supposed to stay in the project forever or? How do we know when it can be removed?

Comment: This will work well, however, if you have not enabled mutliDex on your  grade defaultConfig you will run into another error " Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 89411 > 65536) " To solve this make sure you add  implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1' on your dependencies and set multiDexEnabled true on  android defaultConfig

Comment: Issue tracker link? That's the only way to find out when the dependency can be removed.

Comment: great! but do we need to remove this later on down the road?

Comment: April 2022: using implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre' removed the issue

Comment: doesn't work anymore

Comment: CameraX: `ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(activityContext).apply {
                addListener` - `Unresolved reference: addListener`

Comment: worked for me in unity 2021.3.16f1

Answer (score 31):

I just came across this when building my Flutter project. Not quite sure why it reared its ugly head, but here I am.

So, if any Flutter devs come across this, @Ray Li's answer worked for me. The `build.gradle` file that you want to edit is the one in the `android/app` folder (ie. NOT the one in the `android` folder).

Just add the `implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'` to the dependencies section at the end of the file, as follows:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'
}
```

Comment: This happened to me all of a sudden today with my Flutter project too, happened after I upgraded my packages and Flutter version.

Comment: Seriously man! Completely out of the blue errors like this ruin the overall Flutter dev experience.

Answer (score 22):

Add this line in build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'
```

Answer (score 18):

add this to your gradle file

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Still using java for android. Seems not to be kotlin dependant.

Answer (score 11):

I encountered the same problem. I added the line below

```
implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'
```

This works but I encountered another issue- `Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 89411 > 65536)` To resolve this error make sure to enable multiDex as below

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.techweezy.smartsync"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 5
    versionName "1.4"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true //added this line
}
```

Then finally add the below lines.

```
   implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
```

Answer (score 9):

I added this one and working perfectly for me.

```
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'
```

Answer (score 7):

**Reduce duplicated dependencies from your project**

For example many dependencies uses support-v4 and appcompat-v7 as included packages and then could be different versions, so you need remove this packages from inside of dependencies and create one compile dependency.

This will remove all included modules of libraries

```
android {
  configurations {
     all*.exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
     all*.exclude module: 'support-v4'
  }
}
```

Or you can manage throw each dependency to more clear removing packages like this:

```
dependencies {
  implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:4.2.0@aar') {//depend on your library
     transitive = true
     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
     exclude group: 'com.squareup.retrofit2' module: 'retrofit'
     exclude group: 'com.squareup.retrofit2', module: 'retrofit'
     exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson', module: 'gson'
     exclude module: 'guava'//add this line if you have build error "found in modules guava-xxx-android.jar"
  }
}
```

All of removed dependencies must be declared outside of mapbox in one copy for all libraries uses them.

Comment: First example remove all included module from libraries. If you want to remove few modules from perticular library which is responsible for error then try second example for perticular library.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open `build.gradle` file.
2. Do Not replace! Just add this line into `dependencies{}`:

   ```
   implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:<version>-jre'
   ```

> Note: To get the version go to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava and find for the latest version of `jre`.

Answer (score 2):

add these two implementations to your app level build.gradle / app/build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, nothing worked. The only thing that fixed it magically was to update the desugaring library to the [matching for my AGP version](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring-versions):

```
coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.0'
```