# error with flutter and android gradle :Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'

Tags: android, flutter

I have implemented flutterDownloader (its a package for downloading files in flutter ) in my project and when I add it to android manifest like the doc says and when I do that gradle shows this error

**error : **

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture found in modules guava-26.0-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:26.0-android) and listenablefuture-1.0.jar (com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0)

  Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 15s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

my android manifest->
**Android Manifest :**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kivoc99.mscmu">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="mscmu"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <provider
            android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter_downloader.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
            tools:node="remove" />

        <provider
            android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.FlutterDownloaderInitializer"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter-downloader-init"
            android:exported="false">
            <!-- changes this number to configure the maximum number of concurrent tasks -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.MAX_CONCURRENT_TASKS"
                android:value="5" />
        </provider>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

**bulid.gradle:app**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.kivoc99.mscmu"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

**buildgradle:android**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

what is the problem here ? I have tried to do exactly what the docs says , any help ?

Comment: The problem is probably with the firebase plugin, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60472354/duplicate-class-com-google-common-util-concurrent-listenablefuture-found-in-modu) and please also post your build.gradle.

Comment: which build.gradle :app or android ?

Comment: I meant android/build.gradle, since it has the android gradle tool version.

Comment: Apparently it's a known issue, referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63711300/flutter-building-apk-duplicate-class-found-in-modules-guava-26-0-android-jar-an) you can solve it by adding `implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'` to your dependencies.

Comment: can you put in a code ?

Comment: do you know what causes the issue ?

Comment: Add this line to the dependencies at the bottom of the bulid.gradle:app file just under the line for multidex. `implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'`

Comment: see link https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/53946842.html

Answer (score 5):

Check your pubspec.yaml and find duplicates under dependencies.
for example : you may be use barcode scanner and image picker in the same project. barcod scanner has a image picker inside it. so a problem will be occured as this.

Answer (score 3):

Had this same issue. What worked for me was adding this to my android/app/build.gradle file:

```
configurations.all {
   resolutionStrategy {
      eachDependency {
        if ((requested.group == "org.jetbrains.kotlin") 
          &&(requested.name.startsWith("kotlin-stdlib"))) {
            useVersion("1.8.0")
        }
    }
}
}
```

Just switch the useVersion("X.X.X") with whatever you need

Comment: This solution worked for me. I am working in flutter 3.16.5

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.2-android'` to your **bulid.gradle:app**. refer [this](https://nhancv.com/flutter-java-lang-runtimeexception-java-lang-runtimeexception-duplicate-class/) and [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/69455) for more info.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. You'll need to open the gradle file in android stusio and sync

Answer (score 1):

1. Solution
   check your package basically this error is related your package.
   barcode scanner and image picker  using same class that creates Duplicate class
   also device_info_plus, package_info_plus: ^3.0.2 and storage info plus.
   check your packages
   and run flutter clean and than pub get.
   if not find which packages creating issue than compare pubspec.yaml packages with compiled packages in build.
2. if get this by upgrading kotlin version than add these line in app/buid.gradle file

   **dependencies {
   constraints {
   implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
   because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
   }
   implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
   because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
   }
   }
   }**

Answer (score 0):

If you're using androidX or jetifier you need to have the following in your projects `android/gradle.properties`

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```