# Duplicate Class okio in module com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17 with ProofMode Android Library

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle, dependencies

I tried to add `org.witness:android-libproofmode:0.7` and `com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0` dependencies to my Android project. However, the following error occurred after I built the project.

```
Duplicate class okio.AsyncTimeout found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.AsyncTimeout$1 found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.AsyncTimeout$2 found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.AsyncTimeout$Watchdog found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.Base64 found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.Buffer found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.Buffer$1 found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.Buffer$2 found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.BufferedSink found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.BufferedSource found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.ByteString found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.DeflaterSink found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.ForwardingSink found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.ForwardingSource found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.ForwardingTimeout found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.GzipSink found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.GzipSource found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.InflaterSource found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.Okio found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.Okio$1 found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.Okio$2 found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.Okio$3 found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.RealBufferedSink found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.RealBufferedSink$1 found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.RealBufferedSource found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.RealBufferedSource$1 found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.Segment found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.SegmentPool found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.SegmentedByteString found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.Sink found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.Source found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.Timeout found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.Timeout$1 found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
Duplicate class okio.Util found in modules jetified-java-opentimestamps-1.17.jar (com.eternitywall:java-opentimestamps:1.17) and jetified-okio-1.17.2.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2)
```

I have already tried to exclude the `okio` module with the following script but it does not help.

```
implementation("org.witness:android-libproofmode:0.7") {
    exclude group: "com.squareup.okio", module: "okio"
}
```

If I excluded all `okio` module in all configurations, the project could be built successfully. Nonetheless, the project still needed some classes in the `okio` module (e.g. Crashlytics requires it). Thus, excluding the module in all configurations is not a feasible solution.

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: "com.squareup.okio", module: "okio"
}
```

**How should I exclude the `okio` module in `org.witness:android-libproofmode` only and successfully build the project?** The following is the minimal example `app/build.gradle` file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.project"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'lib/x86_64/darwin/libscrypt.dylib'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.10"

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'

    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")

    implementation("org.witness:android-libproofmode:0.7")
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56639529/duplicate-class-com-google-common-util-concurrent-listenablefuture-found-in-modu
    implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding transitive = false ?

Comment: but, normally, when you exclude the group of library in some dependancy, this should exclude only from that dependancy. That should be ok in your case.

Comment: @mirsaidoff I have tried adding `transitive=false` but it will also exclude all transitive dependencies of `android-libproofmode` and thus causes a `ClassNotFound` error in runtime.