# AudioService flutter package error when compiling

Tags: flutter, dart, yaml

I'm trying to run a BackgroundTask on my application in order to control my audio player.
To achieve this, I want to use the audio_service package.

But, when I just import it in my pubspec.yaml, my whole project crash and is impossible to run again.

This is the error :

---

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> 1 exception was raised by workers:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture found in modules guava-20.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava:20.0) and listenablefuture-1.0.jar (com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.

---

I tried with a brand new project to see if it's a conflict inner my packages. But, even without any packages, I'm front of this error.

Is there a problem with that package, or someone who has already encountered this error?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This (from [Duplicate class com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture found in modules guava-20.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava:20.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56639529/duplicate-class-com-google-common-util-concurrent-listenablefuture-found-in-modu)) worked for me:

Add the line

```
implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'
```

to the dependencies block in your app/src/build.gradle file.