# Several issues with Ktor server authentication in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor

With `io.ktor:ktor-auth:1.5.2` on `minSdkVersion 25` I get "*Cannot access class 'com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture'*" when attempting to build the project and after adding `implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'` to `build.gradle` it worked again, like it was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56639924/9212745).

However, when I attempt to generate a JWT token the `JWTCreator.Builder.sign()` method uses `Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString()` from `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` and I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method encodeBase64URLSafeString([B)Ljava/lang/String; in class Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64' appears in /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar)
```

Is there something I can do apart from manually overriding the entire Ktor class (which might not even be possible)? Note that I've already added `implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.15'` but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`JWTDecode.Android`](https://github.com/auth0/JWTDecode.Android) for Android (even with Kotlin):

```
implementation "com.auth0.android:jwtdecode:2.0.0"
```

Comment: Nothing changes because the code that uses `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` is inside Ktor.