# How do I fix a dependency conflict with guava ListenableFuture when building an Expo app with eas?

Tags: android, gradle, expo, guava, eas

I am building an Expo app using eas which makes use of the react-native-usb-serialport library. When building this library I get the following error:

```
[stderr] 
* What went wrong:

[stderr] 
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

[stderr] 
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable

[stderr] 
   > Duplicate class com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture found in modules jetified-guava-20.0 (com.google.guava:guava:20.0) and jetified-listenablefuture-1.0 (com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0)

[stderr]
```

From what I understand, [this is a known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56639529/duplicate-class-com-google-common-util-concurrent-listenablefuture-found-in-modu) that can be fixed by editing the `android/app/bundle.gradle` in a standard java Android app. However because I am building with eas/Expo, I do not think that there is a way to do this directly. I forked the `react-native-usb-serialport` library and tried removing the guava dependency from the library's gradle file as suggested [here](https://github.com/flyskywhy/react-native-usb-serialport/issues/7), but then the library failed to build because the dependency was missing. I also tried upgrading the library's guava dependency to version 27.0, but when I did this I got a different build issue saying that guava 27.0 could not be found.

What else could I try?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by forking the `react-native-serial-usb` library and removing the dependency on Guava. Only one function from Guava was used in the library so this was easy.

https://github.com/lr210/react-native-usb-serialport/tree/master/android