# Exclude indirect dependencies of Android from Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, dependency-management

I'm using Ironsource + UnityAds in my Unity game, however in the latest version, UnityAds is using protobuf-javalite that conflicts with protobuf-java that other dependencies are using.

I was able to fix it with the following code on mainTemplate.gradle:

```
implementation('com.unity3d.ads:unity-ads:4.9.2') {
  exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-javalite'
}
```

However, every time I resolve the dependencies using Android Resolver this code is excluded. How is the correct way of doing it without future issues?

Answer (score 0):

After searching around, found a solution of my issue on this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64421871/1343916

In my case, I changed it to this snippet, inside dependencies block:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-javalite'
}
```