# Android WorkManager ListenableWorker implementation: ListenableFuture interface isn't found

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-workmanager

I'm trying to implement Android [ListenableWorker](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker) that `startWork()` [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker.html#startWork()) returns `com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture` interface, but the last one isn't available. Also I need `com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture` implementation, which is also isn't available. Which module should I include to make these types available?

**app.gradle**

```
...
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.1.0"
}
```

**MyWorker.kt**

```
class SendRegistrationTokenWorker(
    context: Context,
    params: WorkerParameters,
) : ListenableWorker(context, params) {
   override fun startWork(): ListenableFuture<Result> { ... }
}
```

---

As I understand, the dependency I want is `com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0`, but `androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.1.0` already depends on it, as well as other libraries that the app uses. The problem is that `com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0` resolves to `com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava`, which doesn't contain the required type, it is just a mock dependency.

I tried to add separate `com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0` dependency, but it also resolves to `com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava` and nothing changes.

If I force the `listenablefuture` version to be `1.0`, I get the error:

> Program type already present:
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture

```
android {
    ...
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0"
        }
    }
}
...
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52521302/how-to-solve-program-type-already-present-com-google-common-util-concurrent-lis

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this post already and tried the accepted answer. But excluding of  `listenablefuture'` returns back the previous problem: ListenableFuture  type isn't found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, the easiest solution I've found is to add the whole guava dependency to the project. I'm not sure it's the right way, because I use only few types from the library. But, it's simple solution, which I'm searching for.

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
   ...
   implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.0-android'
}
```

I've also found [Threading in ListenableWorker](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/listenableworker) Android documentation section about ListenableWorker implementation, which suggest to use [councurrent-futures](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/concurrent#declaring_dependencies) CallbackToFutureAdapter, if the app doesn't use guava. I tried it to, but the solution didn't solve the error, `ListenableFuture` wasn't found.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to switch and extend a `CoroutineWorker` instead if you are using Kotlin, which have suspend function APIs that don't required these `guava` dependencies and the return type is just a `Result` object. For more details check out [Google documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/how-to/observe#update_progress).